# Tikz - Using calculated coordinates inside the plot function

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates

I'm wondering if its possible to use calculated coordinates inside the function plot, somehow like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (ea) at (20,10em) {$e_a$};
\draw plot coordinates{($(ea.north east) + (15,12)$) (0,0)};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or if I need to use something like:

```
\coordinate (test) at ($(ea.north east) + (15,12)$);
\draw plot coordinates{(test) (0,0)};
```

Comment: Did you try your example? I had no problems with it, so the apparent answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: I have no problem compiling the example with the latest version of `tikz`.

Comment: Yes I did try my example and now retrying it worked. Maybe I did some syntax mistake yesterday night and could not see due to fatigue.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you need a proper welcome. [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)